# How to get StatusDescription of HttpStatusCodeResult by JavaScript

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a form created using `Ajax.BeginForm()`

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateCompanyShop", "CompanyShop", FormMethod.Post, 
    new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "updateList", OnFailure = "onError",
    UpdateTargetId="slist", LoadingElementId = "loading" }))
```

controller action code is like below:

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(company.Address))  
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(418, "Please fill in address");  
else if (company.DistrictID < 0)  
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(418, "Please select district");  
else  
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(418, "Error saving data");
```

I used OnFailure="onError" in AjaxOptions and I have my client-side script like this

```
function onError(response, status, error) {  
    var statusDescription = ***something***;  
    alert(statusDescription);
}
```

I use debugger in the JavaScript but cannot find the `StatusDescription` (the 2nd parameter in `HttpStatusCodeResult`)

Any idea how I can get status description?  Or I should not use `HttpStatusCodeResult` at all? What is the proper way to return error (apart from validation) in AJAX submit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `response.statusText`:

```
function onError(response, status, error) {
    alert("Oops! " + response.statusText);
}
```

I wrote a post that provides somewhat more detail and a couple of examples:
[Dealing with javascript or JSON results after an AJAX call with Ajax.ActionLink, unobtrusive AJAX and MVC 3](http://www.sharpedgesoftware.com/Blog/2011/02/27/dealing-with-javascript-or-json-results-after-an-ajax-call-with-ajaxactionlink-unobtrusive-ajax-and-)

Comment: Sergi, I use debugger to check that there are 4 properties. In my case, they have values readyState=4, responseText="", status=418 and statusText="error", none of them equal to the statusDescription string.

Comment: @newcoder - I think it's because you're not using unobtrusive javascript in your MVC app; Take alook a thir post: [Unobtrusive Ajax in ASP.NET MVC 3](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-ajax.html)

Comment: @Sergi Papaseit, I can see I have unobtrusive javascript enabled as mentioned in your article.  I also see the form tag is using data-ajax.  The only special thing is that the ajax form is inside a partial view which is loaded dynamically by an actionlink.  But everything work fine except after the HttpStatusCodeResult is returned.

Comment: @newcoder - Mhm... Could you post the code where you declare the Ajax form, Complete with AjaxOptions object?

Comment: @Sergi Papaseit, below is my code. Thanks.  `    <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateCompanyShop", "CompanyShop", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "updateList", OnFailure = "onError",  UpdateTargetId="slist", LoadingElementId = "loading" }))`

Comment: I might be a little late noticing it but the title of your post says `MVC 2`, since `HttpStatusCodeResult` does not exist in MVC 2 I assume you're using MVC 3?

Comment: And just to rule out the obvious, do you have this line in your web.config `<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
`?

Comment: @Sergi Papaseit ,Sorry that I should only put the question in MVC 3 category.  I already have the line in web.config.  All the .js file come from the MVC 3 web application template in VS2010

Comment: @newcoder - I realise I'm asking a lot of questions, but could you provide either a snapshot or a screenshot of what the Javascript debugger shows for the response *and* status objects?

Comment: @Sergi Papaseit,  Sure, but how can I paste screenshots here?  I just find that using status code 400 will give statusText="Bad Request", 411 will give "Length Required" .etc.  But which code will show my statusText?

Comment: @Sergi Papaseit, I finally find this post http://forums.asp.net/t/1624919.aspx/2/10?Response+End+and+Filters  and the answer is that while debugging using WebDev.WebServer of VS  it ignores the StatusDescription.  Thanks anyway!

Comment: @newcomer - Glad you found it. =)

Comment: @newcoder Thank you and confirmed. I use JQuery's .ajax and the StatusDescription is passed into succeeded(data, status, xhr) as xhr.statusText when I switch from the development server to IIS Express.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I think the statusDescription should be response.responseText in the JavaScript OnFailure handler. When you do the following the responseText is not empty, but it's not a really nice solution imo:

```
Response.StatusCode = 400;
return Json("error message here", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```